Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP v1 api With Axios
I am trying to send a message to Firebase Cloud Messaging using an axios post request and for the life of me cant figure it out.  I keep getting 404 requested entity was not found. Installed axios version is 1.7.7.  Below is the axios code.
try {
    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Project ID>/messages:send',
        {
            message: {
                token: <Device Token to send message to>,
                notification: {
                    body: <Text>,
                    title: <Title>,
                },
            }
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        },
     );
     console.log(response);
 } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
 }

I have also tried the following formatting for the axios request with the same result
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Project ID>/messages:send',
    data: {
        message: {
            token: <Device Token to send message to>,
            notification: {
                body: <Text>,
                title: <Title>,
            },
        }
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})


Ok figured it out.  This actualy works, i was testing with an expired device token.
